# MediaWiki: Avoid multiple page redirects

Tags: seo, google, redirects, mediawiki, google-pagespeed

I have an all default MediaWiki website: No added CSS/JS, No added extensions or custom PHP.

I run the homepage of that website in Google Pagespeed Insights and I get:

> MediaWiki: Avoid multiple page redirects

```
(Initial: http://example.com/) | 0 milliseconds
https://example.com | 630 milliseconds
/index.php?title=...(example.com) | 480 milliseconds
```

- I don't think I should remove an http to https redirection for any page (especially homepage).
- I am not sure if I should remove the query string `?title=` and more not sure why it's appended to homepage.

How should get rid of "Multiple redirects" in this case?

Comment: You tested `http://example.com/` in Google Pagespeed, correct? But I guess search engines won’t index this URL, as it redirects. So, the only case where the speed of this URL matters is if someone types in this URL manually, correct? If you test `http://example.com/index.php?title=...`, do you also get a warning?

Comment: @unor when I check `http://example.com/index.php?title=` I get the same result. Yet, if I check `https://example.com/index.php?title=` I get a significantly better result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be improved at some point in MediaWiki 1.34, see [T120085](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T120085).

That said, you can always set up a manual (webserver-level redirect from) your HTTP base domain to the main page (see the [short URL manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL) for having a nicer main page URL).
Although, if I were concerned about speed, I'd rather spend my energy figuring out why does a single redirect take half a second.

Comment: I host this particular website on a (once great, now quite lousy) hosting service. I can't think of any other reason because not I configured the relevant CetnOS server environment.

Comment: I keep up with upgrades and can't wait this to be fixed, is 1.34 still relevant?

Comment: Probably not, as it didn't happen yet and 1.35 will be branched very soon. There are plans to do this but no specific target date yet.